# 4th order non homogeneous coefficients differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm seeking for the solution of the following ODE:

\begin{equation}
x^3y''''+8 x^2y'''+8 xy''-7y' = 0
\end{equation}

I simply interested in the technique...

Comment: Any chance it was $$x^3y''''+8 x^2y'''+8 xy''-7y' = 0$$ ??

Comment: Sorry for the typos, I corrected the equation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$x^3y''''+8 x^2y'''+8 xy''-7y' = 0$$

Multiply it by x

$$x^4 y^{(4)}(x)+8 x^3 y^{(3)}(x)+8 x^2 y''(x)-7 x y'(x)=0$$

This is a cauchy euler equation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation The way you identify such an equation is the derivative of $y$ is multiplied by an equal power of x. The way you solve this is you insert $y=x^r$ and get a polinomial in terms of r

$$r \left(r^3+2 r^2-5 r-5\right) =0$$

The roots are:

$$\{r\to 1.9308\},\{r\to -0.837038\},\{r\to -3.09376\},\{r\to 0\}$$

You substitute these into $x^r$ and they are your linearly independent solutions. If you had a repeating root, you would have needed to also multiply by $\log x$ but you should read more about this equation anyways. Or sometimes you get complex roots, than you get oscillating solutions like $\cos (\log x)$

$$y=-\frac{c_1}{x^{3.09376}}+c_3 x^{1.9308}-\frac{c_2}{x^{0.837038}}+c_4$$